# Erro ao usar Jquery UI e Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou usando `Draggable` do Jquery UI

O que acontece é que, quando eu coloco o elemento dentro da Div de conteudo, eu não consigo mais retira-lo

E é só remover o css do Bootstrap que ele funciona.

Segue o [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mve2u1om/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece-me haver um conflito entre o jQuery UI e o CSS do Boostrap, se mudar o z-index já vai funcionar.

```
.imgConteudo {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mve2u1om/2/

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado Sergio :)

Comment: @Rod bom que funcionou!

Comment: já viu o helper:clone do draggable não funcionar?

Comment: @Rod não. Se estiver com problemas aí coloque aqui ou faça nova pergunta a ver se ajudamos.

Comment: Sergio, é no mesmo contexto do jsFiddle que postei, quer que eu crie uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @Rod coloca aqui com o problema a ver se consigo ajudar.

Comment: seguindo o jsFiddle que te passei, é correto fazer essa configuração? $(".imgConteudo").draggable({
    grid: [5, 5],
    helper:"clone"
});

Comment: @Rod eu não conheço o jQuery UI muito bem mas acho que lhe falta código. A minha maneira de fazer isso funcionar seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/w3g4nqtg/

Comment: aí ele não fica solto na Div de Conteudo, fica fixo, rsrsrs

Comment: @Rod faça nova pergunta a explicar melhor o que quer pretende fazer. Eu vou dar uma olhada também à documentação do jQueryUI