# Spinner jQuery-UI não aparecem botões Up e Down, conflito com bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap, jquery-ui, spinners

Estou utilizando o seguinte componente: 
http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time
Da mesma forma como mostrado no exemplo, porém em uma bootstrap modal..

O problema é que o meu Spinner não aparece os botões de Up e Down, fuçando no meu código vi que quando removo o seguinte include os botões passam a aparecer:

```
<script src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/JS/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Não sei o que pode ser, algum tipo de conflito provavelmente, segue uma imagem quando estava debugando..

http://prnt.sc/dqmxaf[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que isso aqui [Erro ao usar Jquery UI e Bootstrap](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41399/42307) não ajuda?

Comment: z-index não fez diferença nenhuma :/

Comment: Como eu disse, o problema para quando removo o Javascript, não o css do bootstrap..

Comment: Mostre o `<head>` do documento `<html>`, ou a forma como vc está incluindo as bibliotecas.

Comment: Segue uma imagem do head: http://prnt.sc/drq8g5